# TensorFlow not importing properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6.0. I have installed TensorFlow using this command

```
pip install tensorflow 
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I got success messages after isntalling these packages but now i am trying to execute this code in Python idle

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn
from glob import glob
import os
print(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\TechProBox\\Desktop\\A_DeviceMotion_data"))
```

But it gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TechProBox\Desktop\python.py", line 4, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

If i remove the tensorflow import then i get the required output like this which i need

```
['dws_1', 'dws_11', 'dws_2', 'jog_16', 'jog_9', 'sit_13', 'sit_5', 'std_14', 'std_6', 'ups_12', 'ups_3', 'ups_4', 'wlk_15', 'wlk_7', 'wlk_8']
```

But tensorflow import gives error.What could be the possible cause of this? What is this error and what should i do?

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949

Comment: If you have `pip` and `pip3`, then `pip3` modifies the `python3` libraries/scripts. Use `pip3` for both of your install commands. Not `pip`

Comment: @DavidCulbreth i used pip3 for both but still the error is still there

Comment: @BallpointBen yes i saw this thread and i installed tensorflow using a complete command given in one of the comment but still i am unable to import it

Comment: This is a headache using tensorflow in a windows machine. But i only have this machine and i really need to move forward with my project but stuck on just an import issue :/